# What's the most pythonic and elegant way to separate logic of a class and its parent if child class is determined by construction logic?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to construct classes from strings such as `"red apple"`. This would create an instance of class `Apple`, which is a subclass of `Fruit`. The thing is, `color` attribute should belong to `Fruit`, not `Apple`. Therefore, the natural way of creating the object seem to me to be:

1. parse the string
2. create `Fruit(color="red")`
3. create `Apple()`
4. somehow make it a single entity

So far I have 3 options:

1. Everything becomes parameters

   ```
   class Fruit(object):
       def __init__(self, color):
           self.color = color

       def observe(self):
           print "Looks like a tasty %s fruit" % self.color

       @classmethod
       def fromstring(cls, string):
           color, kind = string.split()
           if kind == "apple":
               return Apple(color)

   class Apple(Fruit):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(Apple, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.tasty = True

       def bite(self):
           print "I bite into a tasty apple"

   fruit = Fruit.fromstring("red apple")
   ```
2. The `color` attribute is filled in from outside

   ```
   class Fruit(object):
       def observe(self):
           print "Looks like a tasty %s fruit" % self.color

       @classmethod
       def fromstring(cls, string):
           color, kind = string.split()
           if kind == "apple":
               ins = Apple()
               ins.color = color
               return ins

   class Apple(Fruit):
       def __init__(self):
           self.tasty = True

       def bite(self):
           print "I bite into a tasty apple"

   fruit = Fruit.fromstring("red apple")
   ```
3. The most straightforward way: replacing `__class__`

   ```
   class Fruit(object):
       def __init__(self, string):
           self.color, kind = string.split()
           if kind == "apple":
               self.__class__ = Apple
               Apple.__init__(self)

       def observe(self):
           print "Looks like a tasty %s fruit" % self.color

   class Apple(Fruit):
       def __init__(self):
           self.tasty = True

       def bite(self):
           print "I bite into a tasty apple"

   fruit = Fruit("red apple")
   ```

Running

```
fruit.observe()
fruit.bite()
print type(fruit), fruit.tasty
```

gives the same output:

```
Looks like a tasty red fruit
I bite into a tasty apple
<class '__main__.Apple'> True
```

The first method, arguably the most versatile, requires passing around arguments such as `color`, which are handled much more elegantly in the third method. Yet altering `__class__` sounds like using advanced tools for a mundane task. Is there a better way to achieve the goal or I am better off using one of these things?

**UPDATE**: I probably must indicate that in real life the amount of attributes that `Fruit`'s and `Apple`'s initializers should set is *variable*, about 15 in total.

Comment: should the fruit even be providing a constructor? perhaps the base class should just be a bass class, and there should be some sort of facxtory to instatiate the correct kind of fruit, then Fruits won't need to be aware of children classes at all

Comment: I just thought that calling Fruit.fromstring() would be a nice way to make a fruit. No, Fruit doesn't need to be aware of children.

Comment: "I probably must indicate that in real life the amount of attributes that `Fruit`'s and `Apple`'s initializers should set is variable, about 15 in total." - This is a major code smell. Why are you setting *15* attributes at initialisation? Can you expand your question more so its closer to "real life"?

Comment: I believe you're looking for a factory function, which is similar to `fromstring` except you wouldn't have it as a member of `Fruit`

Answer (score 8):

I would pull the creation logic out of the classes completely:

1. parse the string
2. determine the object to create
3. create object

So using the following code:

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def observe(self):
        print "Looks like a tasty %s fruit" % self.color

class Apple(Fruit):
    def __init__(self,color):
        super(Apple, self).__init__(color)
        self.tasty = True

    def bite(self):
        print "I bite into a tasty apple"

fruit = None
color,type = "red apple".split()
if type == "apple":
    fruit = Apple(color)
if type == "banana" and color == "blue"
    raise Exception("Welcome to Chernobyl")
```

#### edit: In reply to your comment on dm03514's answer.

The major difference between this code, and your "option 1" is that in this, `Fruit` doesn't need to know about its subclasses. In my code I can do this:

```
class Banana(Fruit):
    def __init__(self,color):
        if color not in ["yellow","green"]:
            raise Exception("Welcome to Chernobyl")
        super(Banana).__init__(self,color)
        if color = "yellow":
            self.ripe = True
        elif color = "green:"
            self.ripe = False

    def bite(self):
        print "I bite into a %s banana"%["unripe","ripe"][self.ripe]
```

`Fruit` needs no knowledge of my subclass. In your code, for every new type of fruit, the `Fruit` class needs to be updated, essentially limiting any easy way to extend it. If you were designing a library that I wanted, I couldn't reuse Fruit as I can't add Banana, or orange, or any fruit you don't have *without altering your code* which is antithetical to code reuse.

Comment: +1 for radioactive banana (and I voted up because of the logic separation, not the banana)

Comment: Looks like you simply moved my class method outside of the class :P I would like to know why this is preferable to the other methods.

Comment: @squirrel I've updated the code talking about why the code was removed from the Fruit class. So has dm03514.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Reading your answer, I realize how poorly I've asked this question (and I thought it was nearly perfect). I forgot to indicate that the number of things `Fruit` has to be aware of is variable and doesn't really depend on `Apple` or `Banana`. This means that doing the job your way (undoubtedly the best one) would require crafting a dictionary of parameters to `Appale`'s `__init__`, and the latter would have to decide which parameters are his and which belong to Fruit's initializer. But I guess I can't help it. Thanks, and sorry about my poor questioning skills :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to evaluate what the base class represents.

Does every fruit NEED a color (your `observe` function would suggest it does at least need a default value to not result in an error if it is called)? If so it should be part of the fruit constructor and should be required to create a fruit.

From my comment, I also am leery of your base class instantiating subtypes.  Should a `Fruit` be aware of all its subtypes (see [legos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18971381/594589) answer for example)?

Comment: Every fruit needs and will have a color, certain parts of input string are going to be uniform. Lego's idea is essentially method #1, but it will require passing `color` twice (in reality, a variable amount of parameters, up to 10, are going to be passed)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.color = color

    def observe(self):
        print "Looks like a tasty %s fruit" % self.color
    @classmethod
    def fromstring(cls, my_string):
        color, kind = my_string.split()
        my_class = globals().get(kind.capitalize(),Fruit)(color)
        assert isinstance(my_class, Fruit),"Error Unknown Kind %s"%kind
        return my_class

class Apple(Fruit):
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.tasty = True
        Fruit.__init__(self,color)

    def bite(self):
        print "I bite into a tasty apple"

a = Fruit.fromstring("red apple")
print a
a.bite()
```

Comment: Uh um is this just a comment or an answer to the question? I.e. passing variables is the way?